# how to write case with when condition in spark sql using scala

Tags: apache-spark-sql

```
SELECT c.PROCESS_ID, 
       CASE WHEN c.PAYMODE = 'M' 
           THEN 
               CASE WHEN CURRENCY = 'USD' 
                   THEN c.PREMIUM * c.RATE 
                   ELSE c.PREMIUM END * 12
           ELSE 
               CASE WHEN CURRENCY = 'USD' 
                   THEN c.PREMIUM * c.RATE 
                   ELSE c.PREMIUM END END VAlue
FROM CMM c
```

i want to convert sql query spark sql api how can i do?

thanks

Comment: Did you try `registerTempTable` and then `sqlContext.sql("...")` ?

Comment: hi thanks for ur reply i have done that thing but i wanna do using api so have any idea how to do it ?

Comment: Praveen : Can you consider accepting the @David Griffin answer. It would be pointer to other users as well.Thx

Answer (score 60):

If you are looking for the way to do this using `Column` objects, you can do a literal translation like this:

```
val df: DataFrame = ...

df.select(
  col("PROCESS_ID"),
  when(col("PAYMODE") === lit("M"),
    (when(col("CURRENCY") === lit("USD"), col("PREMIUM") * col("RATE"))
    .otherwise(col("PREMIUM"))) * 12
  ).otherwise(
    when(col("CURRENCY") === lit("USD"), col("PREMIUM") * col("RATE"))
    .otherwise(col("PREMIUM"))
  )
)
```

Probably a cleaner way to do it, however, is to do something like:

```
df.withColumn(
"result",
  when(col("CURRENCY") === lit("USD"), col("PREMIUM") * col("RATE"))
    .otherwise(col("PREMIUM"))
).withColumn(
  "result",
  when(col("PAYMODE") === lit("M"), col("result") * 12)
    .otherwise(col("result"))
)
```

At least, the second one is a lot easier to read to me.

Comment: Thank u very much :)

Comment: You're welcome -- feel free to accept my answer `;-)`

Comment: The cleaner way is not correct, as `col("CURRENCY") === lit("USD") && col("PAYMODE") === lit("M")` is resulting into `col("PREMIUM") * col("RATE") * 12` as "result", which is not correct.

Comment: From my reading of the original SQL, that's the desired result. At the end of the "WHEN c.PAYMODE = 'M'" clause there's this: "END * 12", meaning when PAYMODE="M" the result gets multiplied by 12