# How to append data to a column value in dataframe

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

In spark, I have a dataframe having a column named `goals` which holds numeric value. 
Here, I just want to append "goal or goals" string to the actual value
I want to print it as

if,
value = 1 then **1 goal**
value = 2 then **2 goals** and so on..

My data looks like this

```scala
 val goalsDF = Seq(("meg", 2), ("meg", 4), ("min", 3), 
                   ("min2", 1), ("ss", 1)).toDF("name", "goals")
    goalsDF.show()
 +-----+-----+
|name |goals|
+-----+-----+
|meg  |2    |
|meg  |4    |
|min  |3    |
|min2 |1    |
|ss   |1    |
+-----+-----+

Expected Output:
+-----+---------+
|name |goals    | 
+-----+---------+
|meg  |2 goals  |
|meg  |4 goals  |
|min  |3 goals  |
|min2 |1 goal   |
|ss   |1 goal   |
+-----+---------+
```

I tried below code but it doesn't work and prints the data as `null`

```scala
goalsDF.withColumn("goals", col("goals") + lit("goals")).show()

+----+-----+
|name|goals|
+----+-----+
| meg| null|
| meg| null|
| min| null|
|min2| null|
|  ss| null|
+----+-----+
```

Please suggest if we can do this inside `.withColumn()` without any addition user defined method

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should use case when. It's pyspark example but you should be able to reference it and use scala.

```
DF.
 withColumn('goals', F.When(F.col('goals') == 1, '1 goal').otherwise(F.concat_ws(" ", F.col("goals"), "goals"))
)
```

For scala example see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37108127/5899997

Comment: Thanks @benny-elgazar ! this worked. Small correction - all values inside concat_ws should be `Column` type     Code: `df.withColumn("goals", when(col("goals") === 1, "1 goal").otherwise(concat_ws(" ", col("goals"), lit("goals")))`