# Spark sql case clause - mismatched input

Tags: apache-spark-sql

the query

```sql
  select
    CASE WHEN b.colA = 'ZZZ'
      THEN 'xxx'
      ELSE 'yyy'
    END 
    from mytable b
    ;
```

executed in a spark context as SQL returns the following error message:

```
ParseException: 
mismatched input ' ' expecting {<EOF>, ';'}(line 3, pos 13)

== SQL ==

  select b.colA,
    CASE WHEN b.colA = 'ZZZ'
-------------^^^
      THEN 'xxx'
      ELSE 'yyy'
    END
    from mytable b
    ;
```

Any idea what is wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
  select b.colA,
    CASE WHEN b.colA = 'ZZZ'
      THEN 'xxx'
      ELSE 'yyy'
    END 
    from mytable b
    ;


val df4 = df.select(col("*"),
  expr("case when gender = 'M' then 'Male' " +
                   "when gender = 'F' then 'Female' " +
                   "else 'Unknown' end").alias("new_gender"))
```

[search ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37064315/how-to-write-case-with-when-condition-in-spark-sql-using-scala)

Comment: This small snippet is part of a huge query, and it would not be so easy to transform the whole thing to dataframe API calls...anyway, thanks!